# Slow Select query in SQL with table having 2 million records only

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-performance

I need your valuable suggestion if possible for you, I have a table tracking history (script for the table below). It has approx. 2.2 million records. But when I fetch all the records the table rendering is too slow and take about 4-5 minutes for fetching all records. I assume the row count in the table is quite less just **2.2 million** so it should render very fast.

It would be really helpful if you could add your valuable inputs for this.

Selecting records should be very fast and render within seconds as table records are less and database size is just 12 GB.

Statistics IO and time for 100,000 records - 
"(100000 row(s) affected)
Table 'trackingsHistory'. Scan count 1, logical reads 21036, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
 CPU time = 2657 ms,  elapsed time = 9737 ms."

[image: Client Statistics attached]

```
**Details Below**

**Exact query** - SELECT * FROM TRACKINGSHISTORY WHERE bookedin_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 07:03:58.700' AND '2018-12-31 07:03:58.700' ORDER BY ID DESC

**Table Structure**
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[trackingsHistory]    Script Date: 07/25/2018 13:22:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory](
      [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [customer_id] [int] NULL,
      [master_tracking_no] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
      [carrier] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
      [voided] [bit] NOT NULL,
      [origin] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
      [destination] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
      [service_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [bookedin_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
      [package_type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
      [pieces] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
      [total_weight] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [weight_unit] [int] NULL,
      [total_dim_weight] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [scheduled] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [quoted_base] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_fuel] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_vat] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_total] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_insurance] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_additionalhandlingsurcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_administrationcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_reseller_markup_percentage] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_reseller_markup] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [insurance] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [shipper_company] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [shipper_contact] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [shipper_vat_no] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [terms_of_trade] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [destination_country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [receiver_company] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [receiver_contact] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [receiver_vat_no] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [shipment_contents] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
      [reason_for_export] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [commercial_invoice] [bit] NOT NULL,
      [shipment_reference] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [currency_sign] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
      [dispatch_id] [int] NULL,
      [payment_transaction_id] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
      [service_id] [int] NULL,
      [importTracking_id] [int] NULL,
      [origin_email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [origin_phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [dest_email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [dest_phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [quoted_extareasurcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_extarea_fuel_surcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [payment_method_used] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
      [paymentmode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
      [WORef] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
      [quoted_residential_charge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_residential_fuel_surcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [transportation_payer] [int] NULL,
      [subscription_type] [tinyint] NULL,
      [quoted_markup] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [shipment_status] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
      [shipment_status_error] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
      [is_shipment_delivered] [bit] NULL,
      [is_thermal_print] [bit] NULL,
      [watch_status] [bit] NULL,
      [account_no] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
      [quoted_largepackagesurcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_overmax_size] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_overmax_weight] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [origin_country] [nvarchar](125) NULL,
      [quoted_largepackage_fuel_surcharge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_premium_timed_charge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_restricted_destination] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_exporter_validation] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [quoted_elevated_risk] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [shipment_type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
      [quoted_misc_charge] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
      [last_updated_date] [datetime] NULL,
      [reseller_id] [int] NULL,
      [sales_person_id] [int] NULL,
      [multi_site_id] [int] NULL,
      [acs_group_id] [int] NULL,
      [franchise_acs_group_id] [int] NULL,
      [sk_commission] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tracking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
      [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
)

GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'True value will add shipment to watch list and false will remove from watch list.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'trackingsHistory', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'watch_status'
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_customers] FOREIGN KEY([customer_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[customers] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_customers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_dispatches] FOREIGN KEY([dispatch_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[dispatches] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_dispatches]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_importTrackings] FOREIGN KEY([importTracking_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[importTrackings] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_importTrackings]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_multisite] FOREIGN KEY([multi_site_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[customers] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_multisite]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_reseller] FOREIGN KEY([reseller_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[customers] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_reseller]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_sales] FOREIGN KEY([sales_person_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[customers] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_trackingsHistory_sales]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_base]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_base]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_fuel]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_fuel]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_vat]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_vat]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_total]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_total]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_insurance]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_insurance]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_additionalhandlingsurcharge]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_additionalhandlingsurcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_additionalhandlingsurcharge1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_administrationcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_reseller_markup_percentage]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_reseller_markup_percentage]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_reseller_markup]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_reseller_markup]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__14270015]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_extareasurcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_extarea_fuel_surcharge]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_extarea_fuel_surcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__17036CC0]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_residential_charge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_residential_fuel_surcharge]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_residential_fuel_surcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_markup]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_markup]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__55FFB06A]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_largepackagesurcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__25E688F4]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_overmax_size]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__26DAAD2D]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_overmax_weight]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__5F3F01E1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_largepackage_fuel_surcharge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_trackingsHistory_quoted_premium_timed_charge]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_premium_timed_charge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__22DFFF17]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_restricted_destination]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__23D42350]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_exporter_validation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__trackings__quote__6A669BCA]  DEFAULT ((0.00)) FOR [quoted_elevated_risk]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Constraint]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [shipment_type]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [quoted_misc_charge]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[trackingsHistory] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [last_updated_date]
GO
```

Comment: For info, you should be very careful when using the word "Lakh" as it is only really used in India. Much better to stick to English terms, especially on an English speaking site.

Comment: A clustered index on `bookedin_date ASC, ID DESC` will improve query performance but rendering performance is another matter.

Answer (score 3):

> row count in the table is quite less just 2.2 million so it should render very fast.

Reading 2.2 million rows is not a big deal, but sending them to a client and "rendering" them can be expensive, especially for a table with so many columns.  Why are you sending so many rows and columns to the client?

Anyway, to optimize the query processing, try storing this table as a clustered Columnstore instead of an uncompressed heap.  Eg:

```
create clustered columnstore index cci_trackingsHistory on [trackingsHistory]
```

This will both make the table much smaller, reducing the IO to read it.  But it won't make sending the rows over the network or client-side processing any faster.

Another design that would be better is to make the PK clustered, since you're requesting the rows in PK order.  With a non-clustered PK SQL has to either sort all the rows, or do bookmark lookups for each row.

Comment: Worth noting that the table defined in the question has *lots* of columns which will only increase the data transfer time and make it worse.

Comment: Hi David, sincere thanks for looking into this. I am using sql server 2012, and getting "clustered column store index is not supported". Also I am not rendering 2.2 million records in a single hit. Even when I try it with 1 year data it takes approx 1 min to render complete sql results. Could this be really fast at SQL side only? Consideration - I have 2500 inserts in this table on daily basis. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi David, The primary key id column is already a clustered index. I know somewhere there is some issue, but tried everything at my end with no luck. Desperately need some help. Because enterprise DB's are in TB, I have just 12 GB overall database.

Comment: @Agam From the DDL you posted `CONSTRAINT [PK_tracking] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED`  Also you haven't explained why you are sending millions of rows (of a wide table) across the network to the client, or why you expect that to be fast.

Comment: @DavidG, as you mentioned, "Worth noting that the table defined in the question has lots of columns which will only increase the data transfer time and make it worse". So what you think is a restructured design for this table. Such that records could be fetched within seconds.I will try that and share the results within 30 mins of your response. Sincere Regards.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft My bad, it is a cluserted index only. Aplolgoies. I have corrected in my original query. I am not rendering all 2.2 million records on client side. Trying only on SQL side even for 1 year around 100,000 records takes around 20 seconds in rendering on SQL results.

Comment: Why are you sending 100,000 rows to the client?  What do you mean by "rendering"?  What is the network connection between the client and the database server?  Have you measured how much data you are trying to send to the client?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am just currently on SQL server only. Just checking the SQL and verifying with statistics IO, time ON. Is there a possibility of improvement to fetch faster data 100000 at 1 go in SQL?

Comment: Edit your question to include the IO and time statistics.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Here are the statistics - (100000 row(s) affected)
Table 'trackingsHistory'. Scan count 1, logical reads 21036, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2657 ms,  elapsed time = 9737 ms.
How can this be reduced, as the records fetched are very less?

Comment: There's no disk IO and SQL is only spending 2.6sec processing the query.  The rest is (probably) the time it takes to transmit all the rows to the client.  Turn on "Include Client Statistics" in the Query menu  in SSMS to see the details of the network communication.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Client statistics snapshot added in the original query. Thanks

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Are there any suggestions in the improvement of above query?

Comment: No.  The query looks fine.  You're just sending too much data to the client for the query to complete more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Two things, that will speed up your query:

1. Create clustered index on `Id`, so ordering isn't done by the query, the table will be stored ordered already by that column (so ordering will be much, much faster by indexed column, in this case `Id`).
2. Create non-clustered index on `bookedin_date`, it will speed up filtering by that column (in `WHERE` clause).

Comment: Turczyn - The Clustered index is already there on Id column.
bookedin_date is also added as non-cluserted index in original table design.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the page size is 8 KB. Even if your collation is ASCII, each rows of your table consumes more than that capacity. This means even you create good indexes, and boost the performance on where clauses, SQL‌ Server has delay in extracting data from leaf nodes. 
on the other hand, when a table has too many columns, you most probably need to redesign it.
Any way you have to solutions:
1) Create an index for your query which all columns you need are attached to it as "included" columns.
2) split your table into 2 or more tables

Comment: I tried normalizing it into 3 tables still, the results are getting fetched in the same time.
Also, have included few columns as included but results are exactly the same

Comment: In multi-table scenario, try to filter tables separately and then join them together. I am not 100% sure about this but depending on how many records you want to fetch it may work

Comment: about "included" columns; it is only useful if you include all the columns you need from the table in a specific query otherwise it looks up to the leaf page of the clustered index